# Raspberry 3 with more than one power output

Tags: power

I have a Raspberry 3 with a relay module ( 4 relays ) on the 5 volt pin connected. For this I use even a temperature and humidity sensor on a 3 volt pin and of course i have the Raspberry touchmonitor on a 5 volt pin, too. Can the Raspberry many devices to charge? At the moment only works the relay or the sensor.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you power the Pi.

If you power via the microUSB power socket then the current draw is limited by a polyfuse to 2.2 amps (at 5V).  The Pi will use some of the 2.2 amps.

If you power via the 5V and ground rails on the expansion header you don't have that limitation (but lose any protection afforded by the polyfuse).

Comment: i use it with microUSB. Can i have a problem with that?